# Message payload after serialization is larger than it should be

Tags: spring-integration

### Summary

I'm trying to proxy TCP stream traffic through my Spring Integration application. I have a test payload which is an array of bytes, and it is 291 bytes long total. The first two bytes are a length header in hexadecimal, and the remaining 289 bytes are the data itself.

Originally, I was using the `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer`, with a header value of 2, along with my `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory`.

The message is received by a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` connected to my `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory`. It's put on a channel directly to a `ServiceActivator` which receives the `Message` object as a param.

In that method, I am retrieving the payload using `message.getPayload()` and then handing that `Object` to `SerializationUtils.serialize()` to get back to a byte array. When I print `array.length`, it is 316, not 289.

Why is the payload bigger? I don't understand what these extra bytes are, and I can't proxy it upstream because it is incorrectly formatted now.

### Background

My first idea was that the 2 byte header wasn't formatted properly to be used with the `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer`. So just to be sure, I extended that class and implemented `readHeader()` myself. As you can see, I print the length to `System.err` and it works as expected--I get 289.

However, when I convert/print the payload size in my Service Activator, the payload size is still above 300. There are no other Messaging Endpoints between my serializer and the Service Activator, so again I don't understand where these extra bytes are coming from.

That being the case, it's possible the `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` was working properly, since I still have this issue even though I've confirmed the length is 289 before it reaches the Service Activator.

Regardless of which Serializer I use, how is the payload size increasing?

## Code

### Custom ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer

```
@Override
protected int readHeader(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] lengthPart = new byte[2];

    if (inputStream.read(lengthPart, 0, 2) != 2) {
        throw new IOException();
    }

    int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(lengthPart).getShort();

    System.err.println(length);

    return length;
}
```

### Service Activator method

```
public Message editRequest(Message message) {
    byte[] payload = SerializationUtils.serialize(message.getPayload());

    System.err.println("payload length: " + payload.length);

    return message;
}
```

### Integration Components

```
<int:channel id="requestChannelPreEdit">
    <int:queue capacity="100"/>
</int:channel>

<int:poller id="defaultPoller"
    default="true"
    fixed-delay="50"
    receive-timeout="5000">
</int:poller>

<bean id="headerSerializer"
    class="CustomByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer">
</bean>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverFactory"
    type="server"
    port="6060"
    serializer="headerSerializer"
    deserializer="headerSerializer"/>

 <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundRequestAdapter"
    channel="requestChannelPreEdit"
    connection-factory="serverFactory"/>

<bean id="requestEditor"
    class="RequestEditor"/>

<int:service-activator id="requestEditorSA"
    input-channel="requestChannelPreEdit"
    ref="requestEditor"
    method="editRequest"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and then handing that Object to SerializationUtils.serialize() to get back to a byte array

.

> `byte[] payload = SerializationUtils.serialize(message.getPayload());`

There is no need to do that at all; the payload is already a `byte[]` (created by the length header serializer).

Of course applying serialization to an existing `byte[]` will end up bigger because it adds metadata (magic numbers, type information, etc).

Just change the service to

```
public Message editRequest(Message<byte[]> message) {
    byte[] payload = message.getPayload();
    ...
}
```